# Could not extract ResultSet when @Formula (hibernate annotation) is used

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, formula

In my app there are `courses` and `course_ratings` tables (I use MySQL).
In `course_ratings` table is foreign key to `courses` table and a column named `rating` that is INT.

I will show my problem on an example:
When I download a course which has id 1 from db I want to get all the rows from `course_ratings` where the foreign key to the `courses` table is 1 then count the average of the `rating` columns from all those rows.

For this, I decided to use the `@Formula` annotation

Take a look at my entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "courses")
    public class Course {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
        private int courseId;
        @NotBlank(message = "Add the course's title!")
        private String title;
        private String description;

        @Formula("SELECT AVG(cr.rating) FROM course_ratings cr WHERE cr.course_id = courseId")
        private double averageRating;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
        private Set<CourseRating> ratings; 
}
```

This SQL inside `@Formula` is correct but after calling method `findById(Integer id)` from JpaRepository I get this error:

```
2021-07-14 20:26:26.314  WARN 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2021-07-14 20:26:26.314 ERROR 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : (conn=248) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT AVG(cr.rating) FROM course_ratings cr WHERE cr.course_id = 1 as formul...' at line 1
2021-07-14 20:26:26.323  INFO 15268 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

EDIT:
I don't if it's important but I have added average_rating column as `DECIMAL`:

```
ALTER TABLE courses ADD COLUMN average_rating DECIMAL(3, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution that works !

```
@Formula("SELECT AVG(cr.rating) FROM course_ratings cr WHERE cr.course_id = course_id")
```

I've changed `courseId` to `course_id` because it's a raw SQL, not JPQL